# API versioning via EntityFramework Core at repository level?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, versioning

I have `GetAllStudents()` in 2 versions (`GetAllStudents()` and `GetAllStudentsV2()`).

How to manage versioning in repositories via EntityFramework Core? just like what we have as [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)

Can we have versioning at the repository level? (EF/Dapper/...)

Comment: You shouldn't have direct mapping of API contracts with db schema. That's why you have API layer so the caller knows nothing about your internal storage. Just run EF migrations and you are fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally do not version EF because - you still have only one database anyway.

You version the API because it is a "public interface", not an implementation detail. But the db is internal and IS an implementation detail.

Which is why most people will not expose EF objects via an API - they will project them to API objects (which is a way you can handle changes in the db when versioning).